# Strange mesh behavior with proportional edit

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have a simple mesh which behaves like it has a "rip" when using proportional edit.

This mesh has no vertex groups, constraints, modifiers, but moving a vertex with proportional editing highlights the problem - not all vertices "follow their orders". Only each separate half of the mesh reacts to proportional edit independently, depending on initial selection.

When I isolate this mesh to another file, the problem comes along with it. Here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc4etnzfg7knwg0/OddMesh.blend?dl=0

Comment: You've forgot the link to the mesh. Post it on: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Did you use any addons to lock vertex positions?

Comment: It has something to do with Origin Point. When I've changed it to be outside the mesh everything seems to be normal. I've no idea for now why it is affecting the mesh. It seems like some kind of strange mirror lock.

Answer (score 1):

LukeD was right, following his tips the "rip" seemed to happen along the local Y axis of the object, moving the mesh in *Edit Mode* along the X axis so it would no longer overlap the Y=0 axis, would alleviate the problem.

The problem it seems is the *Mirror X* option that was active in the object editing options. In the *3D View Tools shelf > Options Tab > Mesh Options* disable *X Mirror* option.

[image: Mirror X Option]

There did seem to be some sort of symmetry in the works, I searched for the setting but could not find it anywhere myself, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1kCn0yQrtY) however helped shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I've found it just seconds ago and started to make an answer :) Literally I was clicking everywhere in Blender. I didn't know about this option before.

Comment: I had a faint idea this existed somewhere, but never used it myself, and was obviously looking in the wrong places, like the *Properties Window* or under *Object Data*. I love Blender's interface, but I must admit some times things can be a bit scattered allover.

Comment: Wow - Thanks4 the info - yes I'll watch the video, - this mesh is part of an imported model from an external source - they apparently used a mirror, & the data lock survived the import!